# $\frac{3x+1}{x+1}+\frac{3y+1}{y+1}+\frac{3z+1}{z+1} \le \frac{9}{2}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

I'm having trouble proving that for any $x,y,z>0$ such that $x+y+z=1$ the following inequality is true:

$\frac{3x+1}{x+1}+\frac{3y+1}{y+1}+\frac{3z+1}{z+1} \le \frac{9}{2}$

It seems to me that Jensen's inequality could do the trick, but I'm having trouble finding the right function and the right arguments. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since the partials are so easy to understand, I'd just use Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(x) = \dfrac{3x+1}{x+1}$. You then show $f”(x) < 0$.

Comment: Thank you! All this time I was mulling over the wrong function :)

Comment: $1/3$ does it . Be sure you add them : $6/4 + 6/4 + 6/4 = 9/2$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\left(\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{y+1}+\frac1{z+1}\right)(x+1+y+1+z+1) \ge 9$$

And

$$\frac{3x+1}{x+1} = 3 - \frac{2}{x+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3x+1}{x+1}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1-3x}{x+1}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1-3x}{x+1}+\frac{3}{4}(3x-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(3x-1)\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(3x-1)^2}{x+1}\geq0$$ and we are done!